# Date on x-axis skipping 1st march in d3.js

Tags: graph, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to get lineChart() using nvd3.js
I am getting the data in JSON format and here is the image of JSON data
[image]

now to represent the data in nvd3 axis, here is the function

```
    function getData(transport) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < transport.length; i++) {
       arr.push({
            x: Date.parse(new Date(transport[i].timePeriod).addHours(7)),
            y: transport[i].number
        });
   }
    return arr;
}
```

and here is the rest of the code for drawing the graph.

```
function customersData(transport) {

    return [
                  {
                      key: "Active Customers",
                      values: getData(transport),
                      color: "#ff7f0e"
                  }
    ];
}

function drawGraphForMonth(transport) {
    var chart;
    chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .x(function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return d.y;
        });

    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format("%b-%Y")(new Date(d)); });
        //.tickSize(6, 3, 0);

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',g'));

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(customersData(transport))
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function (e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

    return chart;
}
```

the problem which i am facing is that, it is skipping the month march. When i was debugging..I realized that for 1st March is is taking 28th Feb and for the rest of the month, it is returning the correct date.

Any help on that??

Another issue is that, how can I define the minumum and maximum number of ticks that can come on x-axis?

Comment: This might be a timezone issue. Are you specifying timezones at all? What might be happening is that the date you give is interpreted as UTC and you're in a timezone where midnight on the 1st of March UTC is still 28th of February.

Comment: I am. I also changed my code so that everything is in UTC timestamp. It is again working for everymonth expect March.